# Pass updated local variable between functions?

Tags: php, functions, globals

I creating functions in my function.php and I have a question regarding passing local variables between functions.  Let say I have the functions below, A and B, and I have the variable $amount.  Now let's say in Function A, $amount changes according to certain conditions.  How do I make sure that the $amount used in Function B, is the updated variable and not just the variable I declared at the beginning.  I thought of using static or globals but I am not sure how this applies to a variable which is dynamic.

```
 function A () {
    $amount = 5;

    if(isset($_POST['term_id']))
    {
      if ($_POST['term_id'] == '74' )
        $amount = -20;

      elseif ($_POST['term_id'] == '75' )
        $amount = 500;
    }
   }


 function B () {

   echo $amount;

 }
```

Edit:  To toscho, I understand the similarities between the two questions, but my variable is a dynamic variable, whereas the user's variable in the other questions is always constant.

Comment: @toscho I appreciate you linking me to the other question, but my knowledge of PHP is limited as I am still learning and I prefer not to use a class.  Is there any other method that I can use?  Furthermore, My variable is a dynamic one and the user in the other questions has a constant variable as far as I can see.

Comment: A variable is always changeable, hence the word. :) There is no other way besides global variables, and _these_ are very unsafe, because any other code can overwrite them.